# Javascript help. Getting instance of an array, from and object while using a variable

Tags: javascript

I have an object with arrays in it. The array is a list of questions that are wrong, but I'm using a variable to get the array in the object but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

```
var myObject = {
Q1 : ["Foo", "Bar", "Test"],
Q2 : ["Bleh", "Blah", "21"]
};

var Question = "Q" + String(Math.round(Math.random() * 3));

alert (myObject[Question[1]]);
```

^Random code just made now, my actual code has more question in it

Thank you in advance..

Comment: your code isn't valid javascript.

Comment: I did forget to put "var" before object, but I didn't put my script, I put random code i just made. It isn't my actualy code, just an idea to represent my question.

Comment: So I don't know what you mean by "not valid javascript".

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var myObject = {
    Q1: ["Foo", "Bar", "Test"],
    Q2: ["Bleh", "Blah", "21"]
};

var Question = "Q" + String(Math.round(Math.random() * 3));

var foo = myObject[Question];

console.log(foo);

var one = foo[0],
    two = foo[1],
    three = foo[2];
```

Comment: How do i get the second thing in "Q1"

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = {
Q1: ["Foo", "Bar", "Test"],
Q2 : ["Bleh", "Blah", "21"]
};

var Question = "Q" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1); // You need to add one, otherwise you will randomly get Q0, which does not exist in your object
var indexInQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

var key = myObject[Question]; // This will randomly get Q1 or Q2
var val = key[indexInQuestion]; // This will randomly get a string from the array

console.log(val);
```